# executing observable request on keychange

Tags: javascript, angular

Im trying to implement from where Im checking if given email exists in database, my goal is to detect key change in input field and after fixed delay execute request to db, struggling with executing the request, because im pretty new to angular and reactive.

code:

```
checkIfExists(email: string){
    this.emailToSearch.next(email);
  }

emailExists: Observable<boolean>;
  private emailToSearch = new Subject<string>();
  private user = new RegistrationUser(null, null, null, null, null);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.emailExists = this.emailToSearch
      .debounceTime(500)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(
        email => this.registrationService.exists(email));

  }


  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" (keyup)="checkIfExists(email.value)" #email="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="user.email">
```

Comment: I hope the provided answer is sufficient. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be okay so far. The only thing you're missing is to actually invoke the subscription by calling the `subscribe` method:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.emailExists = this.emailToSearch
      .debounceTime(500)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(
        email => this.registrationService.exists(email))
      .subscribe((result) => doSomething(result));
  }
```

There is one thing you have to be careful with. In your case, if for some reason the `Observable` that you receive from `this.registrationService.exists` errors out, your search will break. Make sure you catch this by doing the following:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.emailExists = this.emailToSearch
      .debounceTime(500)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(
        email => this.registrationService.exists(email).catch(() => Observable.empty()))
      .subscribe((result) => doSomething(result));
  }
```

The empty observable will allow your subscription to remain active.